# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def role(ctx,member:discord.Member,rolerequest):
    if rolerequest in discord.utils.get(member.server.roles):
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)
        mbed = discord.embed(
            title='Succes!',
            description = f'Succesfully added to {member} the role {rolerequest}'
        )
        await ctx.send(mbed)
    else:
        mbed = discord.embed(
            title='Error',
            description = f'Role {rolerequest} couldnt be found'
        )
        await ctx.send(mbed)
```

but why do i get this error? oh bruh it seems like your post is mostly code please add some more details cmon man`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'`

Comment: Watch the tagging. Extra tags attract extra eyes, but if the eyes are not interested in or qualified to deal with your problem, you probably won't get useful results from the extra attention. Worse, if the question is obviously weak, this question is seeking help debugging and lacks a clear [mre], you'll probably find the extra eyes hasten the closing of the question.

Comment: Recommendation: Take the [tour] that was offered when you signed up with Stack Overflow and read [ask] to get a better understanding of how to use Stack Overflow effectively.